# A good xml-based CMS needed

Tags: php, xml, content-management-system

I have to build a simple personal website for someone. The only problem is that the website will currently be hosted on his company's server. The server does not have any databases installed nor can he get it installed.

The website supports **PHP**. In that case, I am in need of a simple **xml-based CMS** for the personal website.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Why don't you just use X(HT)ML and store your content into files? This normally works perfectly with any webserver. You can then manage your content within the file-system.

Comment: @hakre I can do that. But I need a CMS as I won't be adding content but my friend. Plus, why is this question off-topic?

Comment: It's off topic because it's not a programming question involving concrete code. You're basically asking for some software, try the webmaster SO site: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: oh ok. thanks i am new here. I did not know this stuff and about webmasters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it have to be XML-based? If you can drop this requirement, try [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), a very good Wiki that needs no database.

If you insist on an XML-based CMS, take a look at [Symphony](http://symphony-cms.com/) and [Silva](http://infrae.com/products/silva).

Comment: thanks chiborg. I will try these out. And yes, it does not need to be XML based. It is just that I did not think that there exists something like Dokuwiki :P

Comment: Symphony needs a mysql database, just checking it out right now, looks cool anyway.

Comment: Symphony is not compatible with the latest version of PHP.